# At which large cardinal property this second order ordinal arithmetic stops?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals, constructibility, higher-order-logics

Language: Second order logic, with as usual predicates written in upper case, and objects in lower case. Let $<$ be a primitive constant binary relation symbol.

Equality between objects is definable after Leibniz as:

$x=y \iff \forall P \,( Px \longleftrightarrow Py)$

**Well ordering:** $ \forall x \ \forall y \forall z  \\  x < y < z \longrightarrow x < z \\ x \neq y \longleftrightarrow x < y \lor y < x \\ \forall X (\exists x (Xx) \longrightarrow \exists x : Xx \land \forall y \, (Xy \to y \not < x))$

*Define:* $X\equiv Y \iff \exists R: \\\forall x (Xx \to  \exists!y: Yy \land x \ R \ y)  \\\forall y (Yy \to \exists!x  : Xx \land x \ R \ y)$

*Define:* $Y \operatorname {cf} X \iff Y \subseteq X \land \forall x (Xx \to  \, \exists y: Yy \land x \leq y)$

*Define:* $\operatorname {regular}(X) \iff \forall Y: Y \operatorname {cf} X \longrightarrow Y \equiv X $

*Define:* $l = \lim X \iff \forall m \ [\forall x (Xx \to x < m) \longleftrightarrow l \leq m]$

*Define:* $\operatorname {Regular}(x) \iff \exists  Y: \operatorname {regular}(Y) \land x = \lim Y$

*Define:* $\operatorname {icc} (X) \iff\\ (\exists ^{>1} x \, ( Xx) \land \operatorname {regular}(X) \land \forall x : Xx \to \operatorname {Regular}(x))$

**Accessibility:** $  \exists l \, (l= \lim X) \longleftrightarrow \neg \exists Y: \operatorname {icc}(Y) \land X \equiv Y$

This is basically stretching second order arithmetic to include infinite ordinals up to [without including] the first weakly inaccessible cardinal.

This theory can interpret ZFC via constructing $L$ within it. And so it is a kind of second order ordinal arithmetic that is so strong as to interpret ZFC.

Clearly the axiom of Accessibility is artificial, it's just a fixed size criterion denoting an ending to formation of ordinals. That said,  this theory can be alternatively extended further as to include large cardinal limits.

> Is there a large cardinal property that this line of theories cannot go beyond? What would that be?