# Can Frege set extensions of second order unary predicates serve as a foundation for mathematics?

Tags: set-theory, foundations, higher-order-logics

To second order logic, add a primitive *partial* one place function  symbol "$\epsilon$" from unary predicate symbols [upper cases] to object symbols [lower cases].

*Define:* $ x=y \equiv_{df} \forall P (Px \longleftrightarrow Py)$

**Extensions:** $\forall P \, \forall Q: \epsilon P = \epsilon Q \longleftrightarrow \forall x (Px \longleftrightarrow Qx)$

*Define:* $x \in y \equiv_{df} \exists P: P(x) \land y=\epsilon P$

**Size:** $\forall P: \exists x (x= \epsilon P) \longleftrightarrow \operatorname {acc}(P) $

Where "$\operatorname {acc}$", denoting "is accessible", is defined as what is equinumerous to an ordinal strictly smaller than the first strongly inaccessible cardinal, and all of those defined in the usual manner.

This theory easily assures that all *finite* predicates would have set extensions per Frege, since all of them are accessible! This is enough to capture all arithmetic Frege's program intended to formalize. The result is founding arithmetic in second order logic of finite sets (extensions of predicates).

However, the above system has the potential to prove all axioms [except Regularity] of set theory ! Not only that, it can be extended in every way set theory can be extended. So this Fregean like system does perfectly capture the notion of *set* as used in modern foundations.

So, here this theory says that everything in mathematics is captured in second order logic of sets of cardinality fulfilling some pre-defined criterion.

The way to escape the usual argument of Russell's against the original Fregean program lies in the cardinality restriction, the Russell's unary predicate $R$ defined after formula "$ x \not \in \ x $" won't have an object extension (i.e. set) since it would be inaccessible in cardinality; same holds for other known paradoxes.

> Does this system also suffer from another clear paradox? Or it is known to be consistent?

[PS] the endeavor here is not to be confused with the original [Frege's program](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege-theorem/) and that of NeoLogicism which seeks to found arithmetic via Hume's principle. Here, the idea is to provide a foundation for all of Mathematics that set theory can provide a foundation of, besides there is no claim of logicism here, since the axiom of size can hardly be conceived of being logical.

Comment: > Where "acc", denoting "is accessible", is defined as what is equinumerous

How exactly are you defining “equinumerous”?  If by the usual quantification over sets of ordered pairs, you may run into set existence difficulties.  This is a severe problem with theories like Church’s Set Theory with a universal set, where it’s not obvious that ill-founded sets have the required mappings.  …

Comment: (See my “A Variant of Church’s Set Theory with a Universal Set in which the Singleton Function is a Set” (abridged), in Logique et Analyse, Vol 59, No 233 (2016), summarized in the “Limitations” slide in http://www-logic.stanford.edu/seminar/1314/Sheridan_Fixing_Freges_Set_Theory.pdf.)

Comment: @FlashSheridan, this is second order logic, the definition of equinumerous is straightforwards, it doesn't need ordered pairs, see this posting which has that definition:https://mathoverflow.net/questions/422901/at-which-large-cardinal-property-this-second-order-ordinal-arithmetic-stops

Comment: @FlashSheridan, the link is not working

Comment: Ugh, MathOverflow obscured the URL and appended a period.  
• Unabridged  Logique et Analyse article, currently missing: http://www.logic-center.be/Publications/Bibliotheque/SheridanVariantChurch.pdf 
    • Archived at https://web.archive.org/web/20220331040341/http://www.logic-center.be/Publications/Bibliotheque/SheridanVariantChurch.pdf
• Stanford slides:  http://www-logic.stanford.edu/seminar/1314/Sheridan_Fixing_Freges_Set_Theory.pdf 
    • Archived at https://web.archive.org/web/20140413005225/http://www-logic.stanford.edu/seminar/1314/Sheridan_Fixing_Freges_Set_Theory.pdf